# Non-Mutating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a service where there is a `cards` array, which I looped thru in `list-cards.html` component template with `*ngFor="let card of this.cardService.cards`. This `cards` array has a list of object created from API call, and it's rendered at app initialization as home page.

How do I filter that `cards` array from the `card.service.ts` in non-mutating way?

For now, it's like this (mutating way):
card.service.ts file:

```
this.cards = this.cards.filter((e: any) => e.id !== id);
```

If I create a new array variable, to filter it in non-mutating way, like in this example from: https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

```
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const arr2 = arr1.filter(a => a !== 'e'); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

then it can't be looped any more with above `*ngFor` declaration, because it's another array now, right!?

So, I came up to solution based on above example, where I've declared two array variables in the `card.service.ts` file:

```
cards: any[];
// new array to avoid array mutation
newCards: any[] = [];
```

In the `list-cards.ts` component in `ngOnInit` directive I've declared:

```
// to render initial data from the array
this.cardService.newCards = this.cardService.cards;
```

and at `list-cards.html` now I declared `*ngFor="let card of this.cardService.newCards`,

and at last, filter method in `card.service.ts` looks as follow:

```
this.newCards = [...this.cards].filter((e: any) => e.id !== id);
```

I am not really sure if my code accomplish the goal of non-mutating array??

I just find out that on delete action click, only once item is filtered. Every other delete click action is not filtered, but cards are deleted from db.

If I loop thru `cards` array, not `newCards` array with `*ngFor="let card of this.cardService.cards"` everything work just fine, but then array is mutated!?

Comment: `const arr2 = [...this.cards].filter(.....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: You current code `this.cards = this.cards.filter(...);` already does what you want: it does not mutate the array. It creates a new array, which you then assign to the same variable.

Answer (score -1):

JFYI, [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a copy of the array.

Example:

**Copy an array**

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const arr2 = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()

arr2.push(4);
//  arr2 becomes [1, 2, 3, 4]
//  arr remains unaffected
```

Now in your case, I think you are on the right track. You would need to keep the original array safe and use another array to assign the filtered data which you need to bind in html.

Comment: You just mutated the array with a push, use `[...arr, 4]`

Comment: Did it affect `arr`?